# Android- Terminal Window in Eclipse

Tags: android, terminal, eclipse-plugin

How can I open the **terminal window** in eclipse for android? Is there any plugin that i need to install. I am an android beginner.

Comment: I tried searching your exact question on google and found plenty information about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you trying to do with the terminal. If you want to push commands to your android. You can simply just use the terminal/command prompt and just navigate to the adb.exe and push commands through that.

Like adb install *.apk

And if you're talking about the logcat in eclipse, to debug error messages.
You go to the top, under Windows -> Show View -> LogCat
and that will show you all your system outputs and error messages.